# Generic Method to create Parameterized SQL from a Class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, oop

I am working with a Database with 200+ tables. I have been able to auto generate classes based on the Table structure. I can also auto generate insert statements using a Data Table via a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
{
    colnames.Add("[" + col.ColumnName + "]");
}
```

However my goal is to create Parameterized SQL Statements from the definition of the class itself and I am drawing a blank.

For example:

Class Declaration:

```
public class clsCaseWorker
{
    public string CaseWorkerId{ get; set; }
    public string CaseWorkerFirstName{ get; set; }
    public string CaseWorkerLastName{ get; set; }
    public string CaseWorkerMiddleName{ get; set; }
    ...
```

Should generate a Method/ Parameterized query like this (Note Class Name will Map to Table Name)

```
public clsSavedInfo SaveCaseWorkerInfo(clsCaseWorker CaseWorker)
{
    string saveCaseWorker;
    saveCaseWorker = "insert into CaseWorker ";
    saveCaseWorker += "([CaseWorkerFirstName], [CaseWorkerLastName], ";
    saveCaseWorker += "[CaseWorkerMiddleName], ...";
    saveCaseWorker += "Values(@cw_FirstName, @cw_LastName, @cw_MiddleName, @cw_CellPhone, @cw_HomePhone, @cw_Address, @cw_Tribe, @cw_TribeName, ";
    saveCaseWorker += "@cw_District, @cw_Title19, @cw_Title19Address, @cw_StateProgram, @cw_StateProgramText) SELECT CaseWorkerID FROM CaseWorker WHERE CaseWorkerID = @@IDENTITY";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saveCaseWorker, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cw_FirstName", CaseWorker.CaseWorkerFirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cw_LastName", CaseWorker.CaseWorkerLastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cw_MiddleName", CaseWorker.CaseWorkerMiddleName);
    ...
```

Any suggestion that points me to the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should try [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile, `cmd.arameters` is not a propery.

Comment: Why not just use EntityFramework

Comment: @Steve They may not be able to use external libraries in their system. Although highly recommended, not applicable in every situation.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/AquilaNonE/SQLAttributeReflection06112007090016AM/SQLAttributeReflection.aspx). I tried implementing something very similar in a test scenario and it worked really well. However if possible, I'd recommend going with something such as EntityFramework or Dapper as others have mentioned.

Comment: "if you’re writing ADO.Net code by hand, you’re stealing from your employer or client" - [Jeremy Miller](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/11/07/how-to-design-your-data-connectivity-strategy/)

Comment: George, not sure how the "P" went missing. Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

> However my goal is to create Parameterized SQL Statements from the definition of the class itself and I am drawing a blank.

It looks like the start would be to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).  Once you have the class Properties/Values, I'm sure you could handle the rest.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int PropertyName { get; set; }   
}
```

Using Reflection:

```
public static List<string> GetPropertyNames<T>()
{
    string result = null;

    var tableType = typeof(T);
    var result = tableType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty 
                                         | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                         | BindingFlags.Public)
      .Select(p => p.Name)
      .ToList();

    return result;
}

public static object GetValue(object classInstance, string propertyName)
{
  var tableType = classInstance.GetType();
  var prop = tableType.GetProperty(propertyName);
  var result = prop.GetValue(classInstance);

  return result;
}
```

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int PropertyName { get; set; }   
}

var result = GetPropertyNames<MyClass>();
Console.WriteLine(result.First());
```

Result:

> PropertyName

(I'd also mention that I did not do any null argument checking in my methods)

Additionally, there are already quite a few number of [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) in the .Net framework that do what you are doing.  I'd highly recommend using any one of them over your current course of action (if there are no business reasons not to).